# Which data structure to use when implementing Birdson's Poisson-Disc Distribution

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I am attempting to write a function that creates a set of points `( :: (Float,Float))` using a Poisson-disc distribution using Haskell.  I am using **Birdson's algorithm** as [described](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3) on [Mike Bostock's blog](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock).

Points are kept in a grid such that there is never more then one point per cell. By doing this the nearest neighbor problem is reduced from *O(n)* to *O(1)*.

My question is what kind of data structure to use for this grid.  The JavaScript uses mutable arrays and for-loops, as imperative languages are inclined to do. I could copy this approach using Vectors but I feel like there may be a better functional data structure.

What might structure would be appropriate for this grid? Is this a place to use **Comonads**?

Comment: There might be something clever, but I'd probably recommend vectors in ST.

Answer (score 0):

For nearest neighbor problem, there is a general structure called Voronoi diagram. By point location on that diagram, you can find nearest neighbor in O(log n). I think O(1) is impossible unless there is some other specific feature for your problem. For point location, you can use chain method of Edelsbrunner, or persistent binary search tree by Sleator and Tarjan. You may find C implementations in [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/). Hopefully, you can find these algorithms and data structures implemented in javascript as well: [js voronoi](https://github.com/gorhill/Javascript-Voronoi).

Comment: " I think O(1) is impossible unless there is some other specific feature for your problem." *There is indeed such a feature.* For a given `r` in the distribution there will be no more then a single point in any square of size `r/√2`.  Therefore all I need is a grid of cells that size and I can solve the nearest neighbor problem in O(1) with at most 9 look-ups and 8 distance checks. The question was what data structure to use for such a grid as each iteration will add a new point to the grid.